# Humidifier connected to water supply WITHOUT a furnace

Tags: humidifier

I want a humidifier that's connected to the water supply but I don't have a furnace (I have baseboards).
Does that exists?
I just want a humidifer that I don't have to refill every day or so.

Comment: This would be a shopping quest and as such is off topic.

Comment: Sorry if this question looks off topic. I was looking for an answer telling me that either Yes they exists, or No they don't. I wasn't looking for a shopping quest. Apologies.

Comment: Question explicitly asks about existence not procurement.   Seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Search for a ductless humidifier. Aprilaire makes them as do other manufacturers. I have used the Aprilaire model 350 and it works. My 2 cents

Comment: Do you work for this vendor? Do you own the company? This looks quite rather spammy by being so very specific...

Comment: "The Aprilaire Model 350 Humidifier is designed specifically for homes with radiators or baseboard heating systems." Good. So they do exists. That's all I wanted to know. I'll do my own shopping with that information in mind. This answer looks like a sales pitch but at the same time, knowing that the product exists was what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I took out the vendor information because this site has a global audience and may not be  useful to a large part of that audience. If you have questions about this, please ask on [meta.diy.se].

Comment: @FreeMan, I am retired and have been for many years. I don't own the company, and I do not work for anybody. The site I recommended is a common site that comes up frequently when you search for anything related to HVAC , plumbing, etc. I have a lot of knowledge about a lot of stuff. I find this site hard to deal with because so many questions are closed by the moderators.  Pardon me if I occasionally recommend something that is taboo that probably should not be. My 2 cents.

Comment: No problems, @d.george. It's just best to follow SE rules and disclose your affiliation, _especially_ for new people's sake. I often use Lowes.com to supply images in my answers and I always note them as the source of the image and that "no recommendation of vendor or brand is implied or intended" so people know that this is just an example. Often, people _do_ recommend a brand or supplier, but indicate that it's their favorite or that they've had success with it in the past. We've even had a few people say "I work for X and recommend it because..." which is fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are atomizers that use mechanical energy to produce water vapor , often for health reasons . But I have never one to be connected to a permanent water supply . Usually hold a gallon or less of water. A medical supply vendor may have one that can be permanently connected.